# Customizing XML output in Spring Rest Service

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-restcontroller

In Spring Rest Based Service , i have user class and UserService Implementation class

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName="User", namespace="com.concretepage")
@XmlRootElement(name="User")
public class User implements Serializable {

     @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="id", isAttribute=true)
     @XmlAttribute
     private int id;

     @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="userName")
     @XmlElement
     private String userName;
}
```

Output is

```
 <List>   <item id="0">
     <userName>pahilman</userName>   </item>   <item id="1">
     <userName>Rangoon Rowdy</userName>   </item>   <item id="2">
     <userName>Seethakokachiluka</userName>   </item>   <item id="3">
     <userName>sagara sangamam</userName>   </item> 
  </List>
```

Output should be

```
 <Users>   <user id="2">
    <userName>Seethakokachiluka</userName>   </user>   <user id="3">
    <userName>sagara sangamam</userName>   </user> </Users>
```

And also my code has  Customized XMl Message Converter

```
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(
            List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder xmlBuilder =
                Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.xml();

        JsonDeserializer deser = new DeserializeList();
        SimpleModule mo=new SimpleModule();
        mo.addDeserializer(DeserializeList.class, deser);
               // new DeserializeList());
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        om.registerModule(mo);
        xmlBuilder.configure(om);

        xmlBuilder.indentOutput(true);

    converters.add(new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(xmlBuilder.build()));
```

}

Comment: <List>
<item id="0">
<userName>pahilman</userName>
</item>
<item id="1">
<userName>Rangoon Rowdy</userName>
</item>
<item id="2">
<userName>Seethakokachiluka</userName>
</item>
<item id="3">
<userName>sagara sangamam</userName>
</item>
</List>

Comment: Output should be <Users><user id="0"><userName>pahilman</userName></user><user id="2"><userName>Seethakokachiluka</userName></user></Users>